# Add null values to 2d List with Generics

Tags: java, list, object

I'm trying to create a two-dimensional List of a table that holds a single type of object with predefined rows and columns and initialize all cels as null, but it wont pass the test below why?

```java
public class Tab<E> {

    public Tab(int rows, int columns) {
        List<List<E>> listOfLists = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
            List<E> list = new ArrayList();
            listOfLists.add(list);
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j) {
                list.add((E) null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test:

```
Tab<Integer> tab;
tab = new Tab<>(2, 3);
boolean allNull = tab.toList().stream().allMatch(Objects::isNull);
```

Comment: You could show your `Tab.toList()` method as well, but from what i see, the you don't assign the created list to any variable, meaning it gets discarded right after constructor call is finished.

Comment: Also create [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and explain clearly desired behaviour and actual behaviour. Currently there is not enough information to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Constructors can not return any value. if you want to have a list first of all put your code in a method and after that by returning the two dimensional array and streaming on it you would get the correct answer

```
public List<List<E>> myarrays(int rows, int columns){
        List<List<E>> listOfLists = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
            List<E> list = new ArrayList();
            listOfLists.add(list);

            for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j) {
                list.add((E) null);
            }

        }

        return listOfLists;
    }
```

and after that you can use this:

```
  boolean allNull = tab.myarrays(2,3).stream().filter(a ->a==null).allMatch(Objects::isNull);
```

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of a [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) is to create an instance of a class and [usually] to also initialize the class [fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html). I think you need to make `listOfLists` a class field.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Tab<E> {
    private List<List<E>> listOfLists;

    public Tab(int rows, int columns) {
        listOfLists = new ArrayList<>(rows);
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
            List<E> list = new ArrayList<>(columns);
            listOfLists.add(list);
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j) {
                list.add((E) null);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tab<Integer> tab = new Tab<>(2, 3);
        boolean allNull = tab.listOfLists.stream() // returns a stream where the type of each element is 'List<E>'
                                         .flatMap(lst -> lst.stream()) // returns a stream where the type of every element is 'E'
                                         .allMatch(Objects::isNull);
        System.out.println(allNull);
    }
}
```